# Pandas nunique() but only return value.counts() > 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with user IDs, the result of `users['user id'].nunique()` return the unique count of users. The `users['user id'].value_counts()` return the count of each unique user id. Is there a way to combine the two where I want the number of user ids that appeared more than once (ie 2 or more)

any suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mask on the output of `value_counts`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'user_id': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Apple']}
>>> users = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> users
  user_id
0   Apple
1  Banana
2  Carrot
3  Carrot
4   Apple
>>> counts = users['user_id'].value_counts()
>>> counts
Carrot    2
Apple     2
Banana    1
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
>>> counts_greater_than_1 = counts[counts > 1]
>>> counts_greater_than_1
Carrot    2
Apple     2
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
>>> len(counts_greater_than_1)
2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That for sure works. I ended up solving the issue via sum(df.groupby('User ID').size() > 1), but I think your approach is way more intuitive.

Comment: Happy to help out.

Answer (score 0):

There is other ways of getting the number of user ids that appeared more than once. You can use `duplicated(keep=False)` to create a mask to see duplicated values so you can see the DataFrame with only values that appeared more than once with

```
mask=users['user id'].duplicated(keep=False)
print(users[mask])
```

now if you want to know how many they are in total you can do `users[mask].count()` but you can also check how many times each of then repeats with `df[mask].groupby(by='user id').count()`